# Convert evaluate string numbers to text

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy the values in column c to column d. However, column c values is uses "=EvaluateString(A1)" to garner the value. When i tried to copy the cells value using this code

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Data").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
Range("D1:D" & lastRow).NumberFormat = @
```

the data could not be copied. Majority of the cells value in column D become 0. I tried manually copying the values but it become zero too. I tried researching the web, but there isnt any similar problems for me to debug myself.

Comment: You'll likely need to use separate "Copy" and "Paste" commands, and just use "xlPasteValues" paste type.  (I'm assuming that's what you want to achieve - just put the actual values into the corresponding "D" cell?)   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

Comment: I tried using xlPasteSpecial, but it dosent garner what i wanted. This is the code that i used With Worksheets("Data_Column_RevAA")
 .Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Copy
 .Range("D1:D" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
End With

Comment: you will need to specify the "Paste" parameter (as xlPasteValues) - if you leave that parameter blank, then it's essentially performing the same function as what your original .Copy (with Destination) was doing

Comment: It work! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Good to hear.  I'll write an answer to that effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform anything beyond a "standard" copy/paste (ie. when you just use `Range.Copy Destination:=`, then that is effectively the same as if you just used Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V on the keyboard), you need to use separate "Copy" and "PasteSpecial" commands.

Eg.

```
With Worksheets("Data_Column_RevAA")
    .Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Copy
    .Range("D1:D" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

The "PasteSpecial" command accepts different parameters that control its behaviour (much like when you use "Paste Special" through the Excel UI) - eg. paste values, formulas, formats, etc., as well as mathematical operations (add, subtract, etc.)

For reference, see MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy and paste. See if this helps?

```
With Sheets("Data")
    .Range("D1:D" & lastRow).NumberFormat = @
    .Range("D1:D" & lastRow).Value = .Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Value
End With
```